# Resource temporarly unavailable docker

Tags: asp.net-core, docker-compose

So i'm working on an app with multiple containers. I have got an mvc app where i will put information into the views and send it to the api endpoint which will insert it into the database.

However when posting my information to the apiendpoint i got stuck.
First i got connection refused which i managed to fix by commenting out usehttpsredirection, secondly i used my api name instead of ip address

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Save(HeaderViewModel header)
        {
            var model = new HeaderInfo
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = header.Name,
                Value = header.Value,
                LastUpdated = DateTime.Now
            };

            try
            {
                //send to api endpoint
                var client = new HttpClient();

                var message = new HttpRequestMessage();
                message.Content = JsonContent.Create(model, typeof(HeaderInfo));
                message.RequestUri = new Uri("http://headerinfoapi/api/header/create");
                message.Method = HttpMethod.Post;

                var response = await client.SendAsync(message);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
            }
            return View(header);
        }
```

this code comes from my button save/submit and send it to the api endpoin.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HeaderController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public HeaderController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    [Route("/create")]
    public void Create(HeaderInfo header)
    {
        _unitOfWork.HeaderRepository.Add(header);
        _unitOfWork.Save();
    }
```

then it should go to here. however i'm getting resource temporarly unavailable and statuscode = null

my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.4'
```

services:
db:
image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
hostname: 'SqlServer'
container_name: MSSQLServer
ports:
- "1433:1433"
environment:
SA_PASSWORD: ${Api_SA_PASSWORD}
ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"

portfolio-frontend:
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}portfoliofrontend
build:
context: .
dockerfile: Portfolio-frontend/Dockerfile

apiendpoint:
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}apiendpoint
ports:
- "5100:443"
build:
context: .
dockerfile: HeaderInfoApi/Dockerfile

cmsapp:
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}cmsapp
build:
context: .
dockerfile: CMSApp/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixe my own issue, I have no clu what the specifi error was, but i teared down my application deleted everything from dockerfiles and dockercompse and build it right up and worked.